# How to add row and delete row in tableview using custom buttons?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to Implement Tableview with add and delete rows using custom buttons in my app, but i unable to do it so any body please help me?

Here i give my code for delete function.

```
@IBAction func minusAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    print("It is a Delete Button");

    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "DELETE") { action, index in            
        self.tableData.removeAtIndex(self.indexPath!.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([self.indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)            
        print("DELETE button tapped")
    }

    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```

Comment: The question as it is is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Have you worked on any code that you can show here?

Comment: Are you trying to have a custom button that always appears in each row? Or are you trying to have a Delete button showing in that row upon swiping left? I can see your code won't work as it won't know which row that button will delete.